# Insert binary tree using triple pointers

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures, binary-tree

Please find the code for the above-mentioned subject. I was experimenting with creating/inserting a binary tree using a triple pointer but encountered the issue in the `insert()` function, especially at `insert(&(**tree)->lchild),data)`.

Please let me know how to bypass this issue.

```
struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node* lchild;
    struct node *rchild;
    int count;
    int visited;
};

void sub_arry(int *arr1,int *arr2,struct node **tree);

void insert(struct node ***tree,int data);

int main()
{
    int arr1[]={2,1,2,5,7,1,9,3,6,8,8};
    int arr2[]={2,1,8,3};
    struct node *tree =NULL;
    sub_arry(arr1,arr2,&tree);
    return 0;
}

void sub_arry(int *arr1,int *arr2,struct node **tree)
{
    int i;
    int n = sizeof(arr1)/sizeof(arr1[0]);
    int m = sizeof(arr2)/sizeof(arr2[0]);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        insert(&tree,arr1[i]);
    }
}

void insert(struct node ***tree,int data)
{
    struct node *root;
    if (**tree == NULL)
    {
        root = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        root->data = data;
        root->lchild = NULL;
        root->rchild = NULL;
        root->count = 1;
        **tree = root;
        return;
    }
    if(data == (**tree)->data)
        (**tree)->count += 1;
    else if(data > (**tree)->data)
        insert(&((*(*tree))->rchild),data); //rchild is of struct node*
    else
        insert(&(**tree)->lchild,data);   //lchild is of struct node *
    return;
}
```

Comment: Triple pointer: a pretty good indicator that you're doing something incorrectly.

Comment: Yes, especially at insert(&((*(*tree))->rchild),data) while calling recursively.

Comment: `int n = sizeof(arr1)/sizeof(arr1[0]);` is not doing what you hope for.  That is the size of pointer/sizeof of an `int`.

Comment: What you pass in `main()` to `sub_arry` is a pointer to a pointer to `tree`, not a pointer to a pointer to a pointer.

Comment: What possible benefit is there to using a triple pointer?  For myself, I’m unlikely to spend time trying to resolve problems in the implementation because the extra level of indirection serves to confuse (me) unnecessarily.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError but an address to a pointer to a pointer tree will become a triple pointer.

Comment: @chux yes, your rite but as of now my concern is on accessing of triple pointer in insert() function.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yes, I agree with your statement, I am doing these things just for understanding purpose.